# How can I elegantly get two HTML checkboxes to tick each other off?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, sharepoint-2010

I have two mutually exclusive checkboxes; that being so, I'd like each one to automatically reflect the opposite state of the other when a change is made: if checkboxA is checked, checkboxB should be, if checked, unchecked (etc., I'm sure you know what I mean).

I'm creating the checkboxes in my code-behind like so:

```
ckbxPaymentForSelf = new CheckBox();
ckbxPaymentForSelf.Text = "myself";
ckbxPaymentForSelf.ID = "ckbxPaymentForSelf";
this.Controls.Add(ckbxPaymentForSelf);

ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse = new CheckBox();
ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse.Text = "someone else";
ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse.ID = "ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse";
this.Controls.Add(ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse);
```

Based on [this](https://williamjxj.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/jquery-checkbox-group-example/), I thought maybe I could use the checkbox's *Name* property and set them both to the same value, something like "ckbxsSelfOrSomeoneElse" but there *is no* "Name" property on Checkbox available to me.

I could write some jQuery like so (pseudoscript):

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ckbxPaymentForSelf]', function () {
    var ckd = this.checked;
    if (ckd) // check ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse and uncheck if it it's checked
    else // check ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse and check if it it's unchecked
});

$(document).on("change", '[id$=ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse]', function () {
    var ckd = this.checked;
    if (ckd) // check ckbxPaymentForSelf and uncheck if it it's checked
    else // check ckbxPaymentForSelf and check if it it's unchecked
});
```

...but am wondering if there is a more obvious or elegant solution to this, as this is indubitably a common requirement.

### UPDATE

I tried 's answer:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id$=ckbxPaymentForSelf]', function () {
    alert('reached onclick for ckbxpaymentforself');
    $('#ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse').prop('checked', !this.checked);
});

$(document).on("click", '[id$=ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse]', function () {
    alert('reached onclick for ckbxpaymentforsomeoneelse');
    $('#ckbxPaymentForSelf').prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
```

...but, illogically (it seems to me and, obviously, him), it doesn't work. The strange/suspicious thing is that the alert messages are showing twice! I have to click them twice to dismiss them. Why would that be, and could that be the/a problem? I did notice that the jQuery appears twice in the "View Source" although, of course, it is in only one place in the actual source code (at the bottom of the .asxc file).

### UPDATE 2

As wilusdaman suggested (make it an answer, Wilus, and I'll accept it as such), the elegantest way is to use radiobuttons instead. All that is needed is this:

```
rbPaymentForSelf = new RadioButton();
rbPaymentForSelf.Text = "myself";
rbPaymentForSelf.ID = "rbPaymentForSelf";
rbPaymentForSelf.GroupName = "SelfOfSomeoneElse";
this.Controls.Add(rbPaymentForSelf);

String checkboxPaymentForSomeoneElseText = "someone else";
rbPaymentForSomeoneElse = new RadioButton();
rbPaymentForSomeoneElse.Text = checkboxPaymentForSomeoneElseText;
rbPaymentForSomeoneElse.ID = "rbPaymentForSomeoneElse";
rbPaymentForSomeoneElse.GroupName = "SelfOfSomeoneElse";
this.Controls.Add(rbPaymentForSomeoneElse);
```

...and this jQuery, relatedly, then acts:

```
/* If user selects "payment for self" (they are seeking payment for themselves, as opposed to someone else), omit (invisibilize) sections 2 and 3 on the form */
$(document).on("change", '[id$=rbPaymentForSelf]', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('[id$=panelSection2]').slideUp();
        $('[id$=panelSection3]').slideUp();
        $('[id$=_MailStopRow]').slideDown();
        $('[id$=_AddressRows]').slideUp();
    }
});

/* If user selects "payment for someone else" (they are seeking payment for someone else, as opposed to themselves), make sections 2 and 3 on the form visible */
$(document).on("change", '[id$=rbPaymentForSomeoneElse]', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('[id$=panelSection2]').slideDown();
        $('[id$=panelSection3]').slideDown();
        $('[id$=_MailStopRow]').slideUp();
        $('[id$=_AddressRows]').slideDown();
    }
});
```

However, the sections that should show if the user selects "someone else" do not display the first time the user (me for now) selects the "someone else" radio button - subsequently, it does work, though...

Comment: Why not use radio buttons?

Comment: Yeah, that is kind of obvious; I'll try that. I'm not, I guess, the master of the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am able to achieve using javascript as below:

```
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="one" name="one" onchange="check1()"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="two" name="two" onchange="check2()"/>
<script>
function check1()
{
if(one.checked)
{
document.getElementById("two").checked = false;
}
else
{
document.getElementById("two").checked = true;
}
}
function check2()
{
if(two.checked)
{
document.getElementById("one").checked = false;
}
else
{
document.getElementById("one").checked = true;
}
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is elegent you will face an issue because the change event will fire for both. This would be a cartesian product as the two will start a war. the code would change the state of the other going forever, or at least causing unwanted results. Using click would be a better solution.

```
$(document).on("change", '#ckbxPaymentForSelf', function () {
        $('#ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse').prop('checked', !this.checked);
});

$(document).on("change", '#ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse', function () {
        $('#ckbxPaymentForSelf').prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
```

I suggest the following. **Note the labels and use of the class vs the id to assign the event handler:**

```js
    $(document).on("click", '.ckbxPaymentForSelf', function () {
            $('#ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse').prop('checked', !this.checked);
    });

    $(document).on("click", '.ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse', function () {
            $('#ckbxPaymentForSelf').prop('checked', !this.checked);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ckbxPaymentForSelf" class="ckbxPaymentForSelf" type="checkbox" checked/>
    <label class="ckbxPaymentForSelf" for="ckbxPaymentForSelf">Payment For Self</label></br>
<input id="ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse" class="ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse" for="ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse">Payment For Someone Else</label></br>
```

*Note:* When creating the controls server side you may want to set the

> ClientIdMode="Static"

or script this way:

```
$('#<%= ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse.ClientID %>').prop('checked', !this.checked);
```

in the script to be sure your control is referenced

Comment: I added this assuming the OP had chkboxes that were not together on the form.

Comment: When you say "this is elegant," to what are you referring? What is the "this" that is elegant?

Comment: I expected this to work - it seems clear and logical...yet, it doesn't. Checking one checkbox does not uncheck the other (or vice versa). I can still have both checked or both unchecked...

Comment: Interesting. I have run this in IE 10 and chrome. When you click run code snippet here does it fail? When creating the controls server side you may want to set the ClientIdMode="Static" or $('#<%= ckbxPaymentForSomeoneElse.ClientID %>') in the script to be sure your control is referenced

Comment: When I say elegant I mean this:  $('#someid').prop('checked', !this.checked); which says 'that' is what 'this' is not.

Comment: My question wasn't about what you meant by elegant but which bit of code you were referring to with the "this is elegant" comment - your own? someone else's? Which code is elegant?

Answer (score 1):

This can be used for each instance you have in your project, you never need to worry about mixing the logic in for each selector you wish to target. Super reusable!

Since the click event happens on the client side, heres some jQuery to fit your requirements:

```
$.fn.dependantCheckbox = function() {
  "use strict";
  var $targ = $(this);
  function syncSelection(group, action) {
    $targ.each(function() {
      if ($(this).data('checkbox-group') === group) {
        $(this).prop('checked', action);
      }
    });
  };
  $('input[type="checkbox"][data-checkbox-group]').on('change', function() {
    var groupSelection = $(this).data('checkbox-group');
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    syncSelection(groupSelection, isChecked);
  });
}
$('input[type="checkbox"][data-checkbox-group]').dependantCheckbox();
```

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/mJqyqG

Answer (score 1):

I believe using a client side MVC framework is a much better elegant solution.

Eg, in AngularJs, you can bind your view (two checkboxes) to your model, and every time when you change your model, your view will be updated by framework.

In addition, I believe you can also use observationCollection to do the same on the server side (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx).